# How to make feeless(for parachain runtime balance) transaction in Frontier EVM for certain Ethereum smart contract functions?

Tags: pallet, parachain, frontier, evm, feeless

And I learned about how to wrap a pallet to make a precompile for Ethereum users to call those pallet functions ... see the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9KfvhoqLJ4&t=1004s (time = 01:10:15), and code at
https://github.com/PureStake/substrate-node-template/commits/frontier-workshop-2021

in this precompile function at https://github.com/PureStake/substrate-node-template/commit/142fe9a5ca9ca787925d3bd51c55db44caf444cd:

```
impl<Runtime> PalletTemplatePrecompile<Runtime>
where
    Runtime: pallet_template::Config + pallet_evm::Config,
    Runtime::Call: Dispatchable<PostInfo = PostDispatchInfo> + GetDispatchInfo,
    <Runtime::Call as Dispatchable>::Origin: From<Option<Runtime::AccountId>>,
    Runtime::Call: From<pallet_template::Call<Runtime>>,
{
    fn do_something(
        mut input: EvmDataReader,
        target_gas: Option<u64>,
        context: &Context,
    ) -> EvmResult<PrecompileOutput> {
        // This gasometer is a handy utility that will help us account for gas as we go.
        let mut gasometer = Gasometer::new(target_gas);

        // Bound check. We expect a single argument passed in.
        input.expect_arguments(1)?;

        // Parse the u32 value that will be dispatched to the pallet.
        let value = input.read::<u32>()?.into();

        // Use pallet-evm's account mapping to determine what AccountId to dispatch from.
        let origin = Runtime::AddressMapping::into_account_id(context.caller);
        let call =
            pallet_template::Call::<Runtime>::do_something{something: value};

        // Dispatch the call into the runtime.
        // The RuntimeHelper tells how much gas was actually used.
        let used_gas = RuntimeHelper::<Runtime>::try_dispatch(
            Some(origin).into(),
            call,
            gasometer.remaining_gas()?,
        )?;

        // Record the gas used in the gasometer
        gasometer.record_cost(used_gas)?;

        Ok(PrecompileOutput {
            exit_status: ExitSucceed::Stopped,
            cost: gasometer.used_gas(),
            output: Default::default(),
            logs: Default::default(),
        })
    }
```

in my `pallet_template`:

```
        pub fn do_something(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            call: Box<<T as Config>::Call>,
        ) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin.clone())?;

            let special_accounts = <SepecialList<T>>::get();
            // check if this sender can send feeless txn

            // Dispatch the call.
            let result = call.dispatch(origin);

            if special_accounts.contains(sender) {
               Ok(Pays::No.into())
            } else {
               Ok(Pays::Yes.into())
            }
        }
```

Now. How can I specify which function from an Ethereum smart contract(deployed into the EVM in my parachain) to invoke?

How can I pass this `call: Box<<T as Config>::Call>` argument in the precompile to the `do_something()` in my `pallet_template` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For specifying which function from an Ethereum smart contract, use precompiles instead of a regular Ethereum contracts.

See reference: [How to make gasless(EVM balance) transaction in Frontier EVM for certain Ethereum smart contract functions?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4716/how-to-make-gaslessevm-balance-transaction-in-frontier-evm-for-certain-ethereu/4740)